# understanding silverlight resource file format

Tags: .net, silverlight, resources

I'm trying to understand the format of silverlight resource files. There are 4 bytes of the data comes after PAD. I'd like to know what these values are, and how they are generated.

here is the hex dump of a .g.resources file.

[image]

Here is what I know: there is `0xbeefcace` at the beginning, then there is dependancies, then padding. after that is the great unknown (but I really like to know). After 4 null bytes, are the file name and size of the resource. and After that is content of the said file.

I'm not that familiar with .Net and silverlight resource management. would someone please tell me what the mystical 4 bytes are, or point me the url to the specification doc or something.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four bytes are the hash of the file name.